# Spring boot controller not accessed via postman || spring boot : 1.5.14.RELEASE

Tags: spring-boot

I am trying to create a simple spring boot application which has jersey jars as well for some internal rest client implementation to call. My application is starting fine but when trying to hit the controller method, nothing is called & on postman its saying as 404 Not Found.

Spring boot version: `1.5.14.RELEASE`

Jersey Client: `2.25.1 (org.glassfish.jersey.core)`

**Controller class**

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = {SecurityAutoConfiguration.class, DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class})
@RequestMapping("/report")
public class ReportProcessController {
```

**Controller method which I am trying to access**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/email", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public String sendEmail(HttpServletResponse response) {
```

Comment: What address are you accessing from postman?

Comment: Can you please share main class and also project folder structure?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.